# Container of generic callback functions

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to figure out a way to hold multiple callback functions with different signatures.

Concretely, say I have structs `accel_t` and `gyro_t` which will be the arguments to two different callback functions `void cb1(const accel_t &msg)` and `void cb2(const gyro_t &msg)`, I will then want to pass cb1 and cb2 to a `subscribe()` function for it to be added to some form of a container (say std::list or std::vector).

I'm imagining I have a callback function defined in my body like this:

```
void cb1(const accel_t &msg)
{
/**do stuff*/
}
```

My subscribe function will look like this:

```
myclass.subscribe<accel_t>(cb1);
```

What would be the best way to implement this ?

Comment: Polymorphic inheritance.

Comment: Member functions, lambdas, or ordinary functions?  (Some lambdas also qualify as ordinary functions.)

Comment: Different signatures? How you want to decide which of you contained callbacks will get which parms?

Comment: I'd use `std::vector<accel_fn>` and `std::vector<gyro_fn>`, where accel_fn and gyro_fn are the callback signatures taking an accel_t and gyro_t respectively.

Comment: You could just have different containers of functions with different signatures.

Comment: This is a Dispatch problem.  Good article on it: https://gieseanw.wordpress.com/2018/12/29/stop-reimplementing-the-virtual-table-and-start-using-double-dispatch/

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily put those callbacks in the same container. If you get a callback back out, the compiler can't know if it's correct to call it with an `accel_t` or with a `gyro_t`. And it will be trickier for your code to know, possibly requiring extra data.

But to get code reusage, we can use a tuple of containers, selecting the correct container each time we want to use one:

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

class MyClass
{
public:
    template <typename T, typename FuncT>
    auto subscribe(FuncT&& func)
        -> std::void_t<decltype(
           std::declval<const FuncT&>()(std::declval<const T&>()))>;

    template <typename T>
    void invoke_callbacks(const T& arg) const;

private:
    template <typename T>
    using storage_type_for = std::vector<std::function<void(const T&)>>;

    std::tuple<storage_type_for<accel_t>,
               storage_type_for<gyro_t> /* ... */ >
        m_callbacks;
};

template <typename T, typename FuncT>
auto MyClass::subscribe(FuncT&& func)
        -> std::void_t<decltype(
           std::declval<const FuncT&>()(std::declval<const T&>()))>
{
     std::get<storage_type_for<T>>(m_callbacks)
         .emplace_back(std::forward<FuncT>(func));
}

template <typename T>
void MyClass::invoke_callbacks(const T& arg) const
{
    for (const auto& cb : std::get<storage_type_for<T>>(m_callbacks))
        cb(arg);
}
```

See [the full program example on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa5fa9ba381b5b0f).

This does require a known list of valid types. If you really need to be able to subscribe callbacks for any type at all, that's possible but much trickier. Possible improvements include giving a legible error message if a "wrong" type is given as a template argument, and/or in some cases automatically deducing the template argument for `subscribe` so it doesn't always need to be specified.